# Collect equations for a cheat sheet

Tags: indexing

Physics exams typically have a cheat sheet up front, followed by the problems, which are formatted as lists.  I have amassed a test bank of problems, which reside in a folder that contains files, each with a single problem.  To write an exam, I use a master tex file that uses \input to call the individual problems that I want to include.  This part works fine.  However, I then need to make a cheat sheet, which appears as the front page of the exam.  This is the hard part because for each exam, I need to recall which formulas to add to the sheet and them type them out.  Alternatively, I could include the formulas in the files with the problems, then manually strip them out and add them to the sheet.  But, this is inelegant and spits in the face of the beauty of LaTeX.

It would be convenient if it were possible to include in each individual problem file the formulas that need to be added to the cheat sheet, but for these formulas to not appear on the page with the problem.  Perhaps this could be done in a specially-tagged environment that alerts LaTeX to place that formula up front.  Perhaps this could be invoked with something analogous to \tableofcontents, call it \collectformulas, which collects the needed formulas and places them up front.

In writing this, question, I just realized that the MakeIndex package would be able to do this if only it did not include page numbers.

Anyway, is there a simple solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've used this method to add "headings" to an index, where page numbers
aren't wanted.  it should work for other unnumbered entries as well.

```
\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}}

\index{text of entry\gobble |idxnopage}
```

the `\gobble` gets rid of the usual comma; `\idxnopage` gets rid of the
page number.  since both are defined the same way, the same command could be used twice, but i find that using different names is a good reminder of
what is intended.

Comment: Thanks, Barbara, that worked great.  One other question:  Is in possible to change the heading to something other than "Index"?

Comment: @Mark -- at least the basic document classes call this `\indexname`, so `\renewcommand{\indexname}{Crib sheet)` is a good thing to try.